# Expand UITableView Cell to fit Iphone 6 screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

**Using Auto Layout** I have a nib file that contains my `UITableViewCell`. The cell contains an image that hugs the right side of the screen, which it does for the iPhone 5 but not the 6 (its toward the middle of the screen). I have four constraints:

- trailing
- top space
- bottom space
- width

I also tried to set the frame in

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 95)];
}
```

Comment: use constrains on your StoryBoard

Comment: @eddwinpaz its a `UITableViewController`

Comment: @Peter any answer below solve ur problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,
i got till confused what u r asking for

if your cell does not fit in screen, then give the proper constraint to it, if your making custom cell through nib and if you are making cell programmatically then also give constraint through code. you can use the [Autolayout Constraints](http://autolayoutconstraints.com/) tool, to make this process easier.

and if you wanna change the constraint of that image w.r.t diff. device then this code will help you out

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *trailingSpace;



  -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
    {

        if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height<=568)
        {

        }
        else
        {
        self. trailingSpace.constant = what_ever_value(like,60);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give constraints to your table as well in the TableViewController. Add these constraints :

- Trailing space to superview
- Leading space to superview
- Top space to superview
- Bottom space to superview

Answer (score 0):

For auto layout you should use those constraints for your image view.

1) Trailing to Superview

2) Top to Superview

3) Bottom to Superview

4) Aspect Ratio to Self

and to make the table view cell height dynamic to view proper in iPhone 6 plus you should use this.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //calculating the height according to the device height.
    return self.view.frame.size.height * (80.0 / 568.0);
}
```

here am designing in 320x568 screen in storyboard hence i have taken 568.0.
This way your image will view in iPhone 6 plus exactly in same ratio like its viewing now in iPhone 5.

Answer (score -1):

Refer this URL :-

> Dynamic Table View Cell Height and Auto Layout

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

http://blog.jldagon.me/blog/2013/12/07/auto-layout-and-uitableview-cells/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html